# How to use "this" keyword inside event listener inside a method of a class without losing access to class arguments and method arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this

I am trying to learn the "this" keyword use in various contexts and so far all resources I found including the similar questions raised here in stackoverflow are confusing to me. These include some approach using .bind and .proxy methods. Hopefully someone has a clearer explanation on how to solve the problem described in the comment on the attached code snippet.

```js
class Entity {
  constructor(entityArgs) {
    this.entityArgs = entityArgs;
  }
  method(methodArgs) {
    $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Should return the button clicked. Codes seem to work
      $('#result').append('<br> clicked: ' + $(this).text() + '<br>');
      // Should return 'testMethodArg' as per below . Codes seem to work
      $('#result').append('methodArgs: ' + methodArgs + '<br>');
      // Should return 'testEntityArg' as per below. NOT WORKING - this is the problem
      $('#result').append('entityArgs: ' + this.entityArgs + '<br>');
    })
  }
}

$(function() {
  const obj = new Entity('testEntityArg');
  obj.method('testMethodArg');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id=tgtButton1 class="button">
            Button1
        </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <button id=tgtButton2 class="button">
            Button2
        </button>
  </div>
  <div id='result'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In `$('#result').append('entityArgs: ' + this.entityArgs + '<br>');`, the `this` is the DOM version of the buttons you clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword inside jquery's `on()` function will refer to DOM element `button`. If you need to access the parent's context of `this`, you can put it in a variable.

```js
class Entity {
  constructor(entityArgs) {
    this.entityArgs = entityArgs;
  }
  method(methodArgs) {
    var entity_this = this;
    $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
      console.log("this keyword from inside function: ");
      console.log(this);
      console.log("this keyword from parent class: ");
      console.log(entity_this);
      event.preventDefault();
      // Should return the button clicked. Codes seem to work
      $('#result').append('<br> clicked: ' + $(this).text() + '<br>');
      // Should return 'testMethodArg' as per below . Codes seem to work
      $('#result').append('methodArgs: ' + methodArgs + '<br>');
      // Should return 'testEntityArg' as per below. NOT WORKING - this is the problem
      $('#result').append('entityArgs: ' + entity_this.entityArgs + '<br>');
    })
  }
}

$(function() {
  const obj = new Entity('testEntityArg');
  obj.method('testMethodArg');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id=tgtButton1 class="button">
            Button1
        </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <button id=tgtButton2 class="button">
            Button2
        </button>
  </div>
  <div id='result'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Box 'This'

This is another slightly more complex use of this. I made it for myself just to play around with 'this'. I hope it helps shed some light on 'this'

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div')
const keys = Object.keys(boxes); //4
const boxArray = []
const boxArrayDotFrom = Array.from(boxArray)

boxes.forEach((boxes, i) => {
  boxes.addEventListener('click', function logStyle() {

    let w = this.clientWidth;
    let h = this.clientHeight;
    let style = getComputedStyle(this)
    let c = style.backgroundColor
    let index = i

    if (boxArray === 0) {
      boxArray.push(i)
    } else {
      boxArray.shift()
      boxArray.push(i)
    }
    this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = ` Next Sibling of box # ${index}<br>`
    this.innerHTML += ` THIS is index # ${index} `
    this.innerHTML += `<strong>boxArray</strong> = ${boxArray} `
    this.innerHTML += `<br> 'listener', 'H', ${h}, 'W', ${w}, 'Color', ${c}`

    console.log('', this.textContent)
    console.log('boxArray', boxArray)
    console.log('listener', 'H', h, 'W', w, 'Color', c)
  });
}, this);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font: 1.1rem system-ui;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div {
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.box3 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box0 {
  /* width: 75px; */
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1 {
  /* width: 100px; */
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box2 {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id='click' class='box3'>
  <!--   <p>
  </p> -->
</div>

<div class='box0'>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>

<div class='box1'>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>

<div class='box2'>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify, I was leaning toward the OP's ' "this" keyword use in various contexts ' and 'confusing ' sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

the result of "this" in "$('#result').append('entityArgs: ' + this.entityArgs + '
')" is bound to the ".button" DOM object that was returned, this.entityArgs does not exist on DOM objects so calling this.entityArgs yields undefined.
To get a reference to the Entity class you can store it in a variable in the method function. You can make the method function look like this:

```
method(methodArgs){
      let entityArgs = this.entityArgs
    $(".button").on("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Should return the button clicked. Codes seem to work
      $("#result").append("<br> clicked: " + $(this).text() + "<br>");
      // Should return 'testMethodArg' as per below . Codes seem to work
      $("#result").append("methodArgs: " + methodArgs + "<br>");
      // Should return 'testEntityArg' as per below. NOT WORKING - this is the problem
      $("#result").append("entityArgs: " + entityArgs + "<br>");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick! However, Kristian's answer below is more flexible.